# Why is there a limit on suggested edit reputation reward?

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits

Why is there a 1000 reputation reward limit for accepted edits? I started to be more active in fixing code indentation, and other things, in Stack Overflow questions, and I was enjoying the fact that this would bring me 2 reputation for every accepted edit. I was thinking of fixing a few questions every time I was bored so that I could gain reputation and help people to read questions. But suddenly I discovered that there's a 1000 limit on this feature.

> The other way to gain reputation is by suggesting edits to existing posts as a new registered user. Each edit will be peer reviewed, and if it is accepted, you will earn +2 reputation. You can only earn a maximum of +1000 (500 edits) total reputation through suggested edits, however.

I admit this discouraged me a lot.

Is this in order to block people from making edits just for reputation gain? Why don't we just add a per-day limit instead?

Comment: There is also a per-day limit - edit rewards count towards the daily reputation cap of 200.

Comment: But why is there this 1.000 limit?

Comment: 500 edits will also qualify you for the the "Copy Editor" badge - not a mean achievement.

Comment: if having a limit to your +2 reputation bonus is discouraging then you might get really discouraged when you reach the rep that allows editing and you get no reputation bonus.

Comment: Most of the time, I am lazy to edit myself, so I am upvoting you here.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Reputation is awarded for posts, not for edits. High reputation users who can edit posts without review don't get any reputation whatsoever for their edits.

You can get up to 1,000 as an encouragement to get familiar with the edit system and so that you will get in the habit of doing it, but you won't get rep forever for the work.. It's more of a one time thing (or 500 times thing in this case).

Comment: There's already a limit once you reach 2000 reputation since then you edit without review. I don't really see the point in having another limit.

Answer (score 33):

<strike>Four legs</strike>Edits good, <strike>two legs</strike>answers  better

Comment: Not sure if this will always be true. My (anecdotal) impression is SO quality is degrading as popularity increases. If that continues it seems editing should be strongly encouraged to keep the quality level high. The worse things get the more editing is needed.

Comment: That's why you get 2 rep instead of 10, isn't it? I was even thinking of giving +1 rep for comment upvotes.