# No points for editing after gaining edit rights?

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits, privileges

Before you hit 2000 rep on SO, edits to questions and answers are peer reviewed and if accepted, the editor is awarded 2 points. After you hit 2000 rep and gain the ability to edit questions and answers yourself, the editor is no longer awarded the 2 points. Why is that?

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82020/why-theres-a-limit-on-edits-reputation-reward

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, I did run a search before asking the question and just never came across that one. Thanks for the link.

Comment: This isn't a dupe. The other question is about why total rep from suggestions is limited to 1000. This one is about why you don't get rep from edits after you get editing rights.

Comment: @JasonTowne Your question is clearly expressed. Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After 2000 reputation, your edit are no longer peer-reviewed before they are accepted. You could easily game the system to get extra reputation.

The bonus reputation that is given before you have 2000 reputation is to help people to get to higher reputation gap faster, so that they don't need to have their edit peer-reviewed. Once you have reached 2000 reputation you no longer need that little "boost" since you have reached the reputation gap where your edit take immediate effect.

Comment: So you basically make a restriction and then also help people to get around this restriction? This is a bit illogical to me. Also if at 2k rep you trust me enough to make edits (and approved lots of then in reviews), why do you think I'm gonna make edits of lower quality now and I don't deserve to be rewarded anymore?

Answer (score 11):

I'm sure there is a duplicate, though I can't find it, but the reason is simple — the edit points are meant to encourage user participation for newer users.  By the time you've reached 2000 points, you have proven significant participation, for which you are rewarded the right to edit freely.