# Does Edit A Post give reputation after edit privilege

Tags: discussion, edits

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)
>   [Why there's a limit on edits reputation reward?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82020/why-theres-a-limit-on-edits-reputation-reward)
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)
>   [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Hi When I was not having edit privilege `less than 2K rep`, Whenever I edited the post it was sent to peer reviewed. If accepted I used to get 2+ rep. But Now I have got the edit privilege, now whenever I edit any post, it shows my name in edit and I havn't get any reputation marks on that. I can see in activity tab of my `profile` that `revised` is written in front of that activity.

Now what I want to ask that If edit post gives reputation when you get reputation or not?
Secondly after getting this privilege, still the edit is approved or rejected by the members having that previlege if so then how can I see the status of my edit (that how many has approved or rejected).

Thanks